# Как можно получать уведомления на почту с социальных сетей (с чужих то есть я не владелец)

Tags: php, node.js, веб-программирование, laravel

Как можно получать уведомления на почту с групп социальных сетей (vk facebook insta) c чужих групп .Текст поста картинки .
Разрабатывается  социальный проект будет список ссылок групп по тематике.
Необходимо как то оповещать о новом посте на группе

Answer (score 1):

У каждой соц. сети есть своё API

Создаёшь крон задачу, например на одну минуту. При помощи нужного метода АПИ берёшь последний пост со стены группы, и заносишь его в базу данных или в файл.

Крон каждую минуту сверяет стену. Если последний пост не равен тому, что ты занёс в базу - значит группа опубликовала новый пост, или же удалила старый (очень маловероятно).

Ну и дальше оповещаешь куда нужно

Comment: >"или же удалила старый": можно хранить время последнего поста :)

Comment: Да, тоже как вариант)